# Google PHP App Engine Increase Time Limit

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How to increase time limit for Google App Engine for PHP?

I have tried to define time limit manually on my PHP file and try to upload php.ini with time limit setting to my instance but nothing work?

I found this article about app engine service (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/an-overview-of-app-engine) but not sure is this the solution and what should I do?

I have tried to change the app.yaml file:

```
manual_scaling: instances: 5
```

But when I try to run it, it return server error?

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What error messages do you get in the logs of the Developers Console?  Is it a [`DeadlineExceededError`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors)?  What time limit do you mean?  Note the default timeout for App Engine instances is 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't increase the GAE instance time limit. It's set to around 60 seconds for all App Engine requests. The [Request Timer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/how-requests-are-handled#PHP_The_request_timer) can be used to handle a timeout in your application, but as stated in the article:

> App Engine is optimized for applications with short-lived requests, typically those that take a few hundred milliseconds. An efficient app responds quickly for the majority of requests. An app that doesn't will not scale well with App Engine's infrastructure.

I would suggest using Pub/Sub and a background process to perform any tasks expected to take over 60 seconds.